# Dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 - The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu with windows 10. My laptop is UEFI mode. I get this message when trying to install Ubuntu.

“The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as a Reserved BIOS boot area and should be at least 1MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot. If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, boot loader installation may fail later, although it may still be possible to install the boot loader to a partition.”

I read the post here [Ubuntu Error : "The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610873/ubuntu-error-the-partition-table-format-in-use-on-your-disks-normally-require) which says that I am installing in BIOS mode, but they also tell me to visit the website https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI to shows install with screen shots for both BIOS(purple) & UEFI(grub menu), so you know which you are using.

This is the picture that I get when booting Ubuntu. So is this BIOS or UEFI? It looks UEFI. If it is UEFI then why am I getting the above message?

[image]

Comment: You have booted in BIOS/CSM/Legacy  boot mode as that requires the bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. You want to reboot in UEFI boot mode and then install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. You may have to turn on allow USB boot in UEFI settings. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Best to use Windows to shrink the Windows partition & reboot so it can run chkdsk. Make sure Windows fast start up is off

Comment: See [my page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on BIOS/CSM/legacy support, why it can cause problems, and (most importantly for you) how to control it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to create your OS bootable drive using RUFUS imager tool by selecting the partition scheme as GBT and its by default select the target system as UEFI only.

Pre-Requisites:

1. Above method is for the laptops which comes with pre-installed windows with UEFI Mode.
2. Disable secure boot, else every time when you boot into windows, it would ask you enter the "boot recovery key"