# Help with SSD and HDD on dual boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am thinking of switching to Ubuntu Linux from Windows 10, but I still want to dual boot windows. I plan to dual boot by installing Windows 10 first because I was recommended to with Ubuntu later. I am using a 1TB SSD and a 2TB HDD and I wanted to ask how I could install my applications to my HDD. In windows, I could have the user directory (documents, downloads, videos, etc) and some applications allowed me to choose where to install. Is there something similar to this where I can have my documents and downloads as well as my applications in my separate 2TB HDD? I want to keep my SSD relatively clean.

Comment: Just one thought: unused SSD is wasted SSD...

Comment: What is the difference. I just bought a 1TB 970 Evo Plus SSD from amazon recently

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to install Windows in the SSD and Ubuntu in the HDD (or the other way around)? Do you want to install both in the SSD and keep your documents, downloads, video etc. in the HDD? If so, do you want to keep them in a way so that they can be accessed both from Windows and Ubuntu? Ubuntu (Linux in general) do not install apps the same way as Windows. Most apps are stored in different system folders. If you install Ubuntu in the SSD there is no easy way to put the Ubuntu apps in the HDD.

Comment: I would like to install and dual boot both on the SSD. It would also be nice if both documents, downloads, video etc could be available on both operating systems. I want to be able to install apps for ubuntu on the HDD instead of the SSD. What can I do?

Comment: Installing Ubuntu apps in the HDD is harder to do. Ubuntu does not have a "Programs" folder like Windows. Neither do you get an option to choose installation folder like you do in Windows. Various files from each app gets moved to various systems folders in Ubuntu. The rest can be done.

Comment: Be sure both are UEFI boot mode. Older /boot & swap not required.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme &
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/610873/ubuntu-error-the-partition-table-format-in-use-on-your-disks-normally-require/610888#610888
& 
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi